# Removing rows from a dataframe by identifying rows to keep

Tags: python, pandas

I'm interested in keeping a handful of people who are males from a dataset. How do I let Python know I want to keep X, Y, and Z males and to drop the rest of the males? For example, say I start with this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Salary':[8700,6300,4700,2100,3400], 'Gender':['Male','Female','Male','Female','Male']},index=pd.Series(['Joe Smith', 'Jane Doe', 'Rob Dole', 'Sue Pam', 'Jack Li'], name='Name'))

print df1

           Gender  Salary
Name                     
Joe Smith    Male    8700
Jane Doe   Female    6300
Rob Dole     Male    4700
Sue Pam    Female    2100
Jack Li      Male    3400
```

Of the males in the dataframe, I want to keep Joe Smith and Rob Dole and remove all of the other males. What's the fastest way to do this across thousands of names with gender identifiers? I have a list of about 20-25 names that I would like to keep among the thousands. My final dataframe should look like this:

```
           Gender  Salary
Name                     
Joe Smith    Male    8700
Jane Doe   Female    6300
Rob Dole     Male    4700
Sue Pam    Female    2100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your condition is :

```
cond=(df1.Gender=='Female') | (df1.index.isin(['Joe Smith','Rob Dole']))
```

and your will simply `df1[cond]`.

Comment: Would this work if I have more than two gender identifiers? For example, in addition to Male, Female, I also have Unknown and No Answer.

Comment: if you will, `df1.Gender!='Male'` give you another criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
In [14]: df1.query("Gender in ['Female','Unknown'] or Name in ['Joe Smith','Rob Dole']")
Out[14]:
           Gender  Salary
Name
Joe Smith    Male    8700
Jane Doe   Female    6300
Rob Dole     Male    4700
Sue Pam    Female    2100
```